# Snapshottable directory hadoop admin

Tags: hadoop

What is a snapshottable directory in hadoop used for? and how does it work?
 Following is the output of my snapshotabble directory

```
$hadoop fs -ls -R /Snap/.snapshot
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-09 13:04 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-09 13:04 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew1
```

What is these folders Sanpnew and Sanpnew1 used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDFS Snapshots are read-only point-in-time copies of the entire HDFS file system or a subtree/portion of it. These snapshots can be used for Data Recovery and Backup

In this example posted,

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-09 13:04 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew
```

`/Snap` is a snapshottable directory, which means snapshots can be created for this directory. Every snapshottable directory will contain a subdirectory `.snapshot` to store the snapshots created.

And there are two snapshots(`Sanpnew` and `Sanpnew1`) created for the directory `/Snap`.

These snapshot folders hold the image of the `/Snap` directory as it was at the time of snapshot creation. These can be used for say, for example if the contents of this directory `/Snap` requires to be rolled-back (to an earlier point in time), then these snapshots can be made to use.

Refer this document [HDFS Snapshots](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. That was great help from ur side

Comment: But when i checked it showed 0 bytes for Sanpnew and Sanpnew1.That means its empty right. how can i find the image residing inside Sanpnew and Sanpnew1

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-08 21:34 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-08 21:34 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew1

Comment: It is a directory. If you had files inside `Snap`, they will be inside `Sanpnew` as well

Comment: I checked that as well but still i coudnt find the same file inside Sanpnew

Comment: Output of Snap folder

Comment: hadoop@impc2391:~$ hadoop fs -ls /Snap
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup         19 2017-03-09 02:36 /Snap/teest1

Comment: Output of Sanpnew1

Comment: hadoop@impc2391:~$ hadoop fs -ls -R /Snap/.snapshot
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-08 21:34 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2017-03-08 21:34 /Snap/.snapshot/Sanpnew1